# Ruby on Rails DB Migration Script Using Text instead of :string varchar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration

I'm a beginner at Ruby on Rails so I apologize if this is quite obvious, but I'm trying to learn how to write the database migration scripts and I'd like to change the following long_description to a text value instead of string:

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up  
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.column "short_description", :string
      t.column "long_description", :string
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas how this is possible?

Comment: Actually, it would be nice to know all of the available types

Comment: The available types are documented here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#M001983

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :short_description
      t.text :long_description
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  def self.down
    # don't forget the down method
  end
end
```

Also, don't forget the `down` method.

Migration types are listed [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html).

- :string
- :text
- :integer
- :float
- :decimal
- :datetime
- :timestamp
- :time
- :date
- :binary
- :boolean

Answer (score 0):

```
create_table :articles do |t|
  t.column 'long_description', :text
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Set it to :text

Here's a good ref for you: [Here](http://niugrad.blogspot.com/2008/03/ruby-rails-column-type-to-mysql.html)